# Qt6 Multimedia module doesn't play audio on raspberry pi 4

Tags: qmediaplayer, qt6

I have builded Qt6 with QtMultimedia based on GStreamer 1.0, but QMediaPlayer not play audio file.

Follow the Qt6 I have instancied QMediaPlayer in this way:

```
m_player = new QMediaPlayer;
QAudioOutput output;
m_player->setAudioOutput(&output);
```

Adding GST_DBG,the log prints these msgs:

```
0:02:50.864485075 1406 0xa7f0b850 WARN baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3676:gst_base_parse_loop: error: Internal data stream error.
0:02:50.864714740 1406 0xa7f0b850 WARN baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3676:gst_base_parse_loop: error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
```

While QMediaPlayer slot error is triggered with “Invalid media type”.

I obtains these msgs with whetever file I try to play (also wave).

If I run outside Qt

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=file:///home/pi/audio/notify.wav
```

I get:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-wav
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst/wavparse/gstwavparse.c(2308): gst_wavparse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstWavParse:wavparse0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Execution ended after 0:00:00.000297388
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

But If I run:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/pi/audio/notify.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! alsasink
```

the sound is played.

I would like to know if QtMultimedia works at least for audio on pi4!

After some tests with MediaPlayer example, I have found that with kms not sound at all, meanwhile with fkms only analog audio works, also if hdmi output is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue on Raspberry Pi 4 Bullseye, and will attempt a fix based on GStreamer.

According to the following article:
https://qengineering.eu/install-gstreamer-1.18-on-raspberry-pi-4.html

There are some missing libraries on Raspberry Pi that might be used and can be installed in the following way:

```
# install a missing dependency
$ sudo apt-get install libx264-dev libjpeg-dev
# install the remaining plugins
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev \
     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
     libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev \
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
     gstreamer1.0-tools
# install some optional plugins
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3
# if you have Qt5 install this plugin
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-qt5
# install if you want to work with audio
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

After trying these I will edit the response.